# How to find the width of the div or check whether horizontal scroll appears or not?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I want to print the page (div) if there is no horizontal scroll appear for that div.
I have a div (1000px) with dynamic data which having property `overflow:auto;`. So, I want to print the div only if div's width is not getting crossed.
to achieve this i used following method of a Javascript

```
var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
```

But it gives 1000px; only although I can see horizontal scrollbar for the div.

What should I do to achieve this?

Can I check whether horizontal scrollbar is appear for the div or not?

Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** I don't want to use any Javascript library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollWidth`,  `clientWidth` did the trick

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("grid_print");
if (mydiv.scrollWidth > mydiv.clientWidth){
  alert("limit exceeds")
}
```